# Rendering issue: line not continuously connected

Tags: wpf, scichart

I'm creating charts by using scichart.

When I’m trying to draw FastLineRenderableSeries with AntiAliasing set to true and StrokeThickness set to 1, I get lines which are not continuously connected (see screenshots). How can I avoid this? – don’t wan’t to thicken the lines.

[image]

[image]

By drawing a live chart this effect/issue causes flickering.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you got a code sample of how you have configured the SciChartSurface ?

Comment: I'm using the **Direct3D10RenderSurface** as RenderSurface with **UseAlternativeFillSource** set to **true**. Nothing more special...

Comment: Actually the second screenshot i've posted is from the SciChart v4 WPF Examples Suite (not my configuration). Just the first one is my. I've recognized that there are much better results by drawing lines with a thickness of two. Need to have thin lines though.

Comment: I'm suspecting this might be limited to DirectX mode only (which is enabled by default in the SciChart WPF v4 examples). Can you disable DirectX and comment if the speckling goes away?

Comment: Aha you've already confirmed. OK will investigate

Comment: Thanks! I've tried the HighQualityRenderSurface on SciChart v4 WPF Examples Suite (v.4.2.1.9358) - speckling is stil there.